# tranformacion de excel con python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, modelos, etl

estoy usando el modelo bert y condiciones para limpiar el excel y en el excel me mandan a veces este valor "                                    -  " puesto el guion y esta columna es de tipo numérico ya aplico la propiedad strip y no lo elimina y no se que hacer asi le tengo el codigo

class LimpiezaNumericaBERT:
def **init**(self):
self.tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
self.model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

```
def obtener_embedding(self, texto):
    tokens = self.tokenizer(texto, return_tensors='pt')
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = self.model(**tokens)
    return np.mean(outputs.last_hidden_state.numpy(), axis=1)

def limpiar_valor_numerico(self, valor):
    try:
        # Intenta convertir el valor a un número
        numero = float(valor)
        return numero
    except ValueError:
        # Si no se puede convertir, aplica el modelo de BERT para limpiar el valor
        return self.limpiar_con_bert(valor)

def contiene_espacios_y_guiones_sin_numeros(self, texto):

   números

    return all(c == ' ' or c == '-' for c in texto if not c.isdigit() or c == '-')

def limpiar_con_bert(self, texto):
    # Obtén la representación embebida del texto mediante BERT
    embedding = self.obtener_embedding(texto)

    # Verifica si el texto contiene espacios y guiones sin números
    if self.contiene_espacios_y_guiones_sin_numeros(texto):
        # Si es así, reemplaza por 0
        return 0
    else:
        return "valor a cambiar"

def remover_tildes(self, texto):
    return ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', texto) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))

def limpiar_valor_numerico_en_columna(self, columna):
    # Verifica si la columna contiene solo valores numéricos
    if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(columna):
        # Limpia y convierte a numérico todas las celdas de la columna
        columna = columna.apply(lambda x: self.limpiar_valor_numerico(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)

        # Elimina espacios en blanco de izquierda
        columna = columna.apply(lambda x: str(x).lstrip() if pd.notnull(x) else x)

    else:
        # Si la columna no es de tipo numérico, deja los valores como están
        columna = columna.apply(lambda x: x if pd.notnull(x) else x)

    return columna
```

y este lo llamo de este metodo

def edit_all_numeric_columns(self, file_path):
df_dict = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None)

```
    hojas_a_analizar = ["FORM 2 GASTO AO&M-C SPEE",
                        "FORM 3 CALIDAD SPEE",
                        "FORM 4 RA SPEE",
                        "FORM 5 SIGDE SPEE",
                        "FORM 6 EXPANSION SPEE",
                        "FORM 7 DISPON_CONFIAB SPEE",
                        "FORM 8 O-PROGRAMAS SPEE",
                        "FORM 9 O-RECURSOS SPEE",
                        "FORM 2 GASTO AO&M SAPG",
                        "FORM 3 CALIDAD SAPG",
                        "FORM 4 EXPANSION SAPG",
                        "FORM 5 O-PROGRAMAS SAPG",
                        "FORM 6 O-RECURSOS SAPG"]

    excepciones = {
        "FORM 3 CALIDAD SPEE": ["distribuidoras",
                                "proyecto_arraste",
                                "proyecto_calif_ecostos",
                                "ano_calificacion",
                                "codigo_ecostos",
                                "cod_proyecto_edds",
                                "nombre_proyecto",
                                "objeto_proyecto",
                                "provincia",
                                "canton",
                                "parroquia",
                                "etapa_funcional",
                                "estado_proyecto",
                                "ejec_proyecto",
                                "fecha_inicio_proyecto",
                                "fecha_pro_fin_proyecto",
                                "fecha_fin_proyecto",
                                "observaciones"],
        "FORM 2 GASTO AO&M-C SPEE": ["distribuidoras",
                                "arrastre_nro_partida",
                                "descripcion_partida",
                                "etapa_funcional",
                                "tipo_gasto",
                                "grupo_gasto"],
        "FORM 4 RA SPEE": [     "distribuidora",
                                "proyecto_arraste",
                                "proyecto_calif_ecostos",
                                "ano_calificacion",
                                "codigo_ecostos",
                                "cod_proyecto_edd",
                                "nombre_proyecto",
                                "objeto_proyecto",
                                "provincia",
                                "canton",
                                "parroquia",
                                "etapa_funcional",
                                "estado_proyecto",
                                "ejec_proyecto",
                                "fecha_inicio_proyecto",
                                "fecha_pro_fin_proyecto",
                                "fecha_fin_proyecto",
                                "observaciones" ],
        "FORM 5 SIGDE SPEE":[   "distribuidora",
                                "proyecto_arraste",
                                "ano_calificacion",
                                "cod_proyecto_edd",
                                "nombre_proyecto",
                                "objeto_proyecto",
                                "provincia",
                                "canton",
                                "parroquia",
                                "etapa_funcional",
                                "estado_proyecto",
                                "ejec_proyecto",
                                "fecha_inicio_proyecto",
                                "fecha_pro_fin_proyecto",
                                "fecha_fin_proyecto",
                                "observaciones"  ],
        "FORM 6 EXPANSION SPEE":["distribuidora",
                                "proyecto_arraste",
                                "ano_calificacion",
                                "cod_proyecto_edd",
                                "nombre_proyecto",
                                "objeto_proyecto",
                                "provincia",
                                "canton",
                                "parroquia",
                                "etapa_funcional",
                                "estado_proyecto",
                                "ejec_proyecto",
                                "fecha_inicio_proyecto",
                                "fecha_pro_fin_proyecto",
                                "fecha_fin_proyecto",
                                "observaciones"  ],          
        "FORM 7 DISPON_CONFIAB SPEE":["descripcion",
                                "etapa_funcional"],
        "FORM 8 O-PROGRAMAS SPEE":["otros_programas_proy",
                                "programa",
                                "etapa_funcional",
                                "observaciones"],
        "FORM 9 O-RECURSOS SPEE": ["otros_recursos_proy",
                                "programa",
                                "etapa_funcional",
                                "observaciones"],
        "FORM 2 GASTO AO&M SAPG": ["distribuidora",
                                "arrastre_nro_partida",
                                "descripcion_partida",
                                "etapa_funcional",
                                "tipo_gasto",
                                "grupo_gasto"],
        "FORM 3 CALIDAD SPEE": ["distribuidora",
                                "proyecto_arraste",
                                "proyecto_calif_ecostos",
                                "ano_calificacion",
                                "codigo_ecostos",
                                "cod_proyecto_edd",
                                "nombre_proyecto",
                                "objeto_proyecto",
                                "provincia",
                                "canton",
                                "parroquia",
                                "estado_proyecto",
                                "ejec_proyecto",
                                "fecha_inicio_proyecto",
                                "fecha_pro_fin_proyecto",
                                "fecha_fin_proyecto",
                                "observaciones"],
        "FORM 4 EXPANSION SAPG": ["distribuidora",
                                "proyecto_arraste",
                                "proyecto_calif_eco",
                                "ano_calificacion",
                                "codigo_ecostos",
                                "cod_proyecto_edd",
                                "nombre_proyecto",
                                "objeto_proyecto",
                                "provincia",
                                "canton",
                                "parroquia",
                                "estado_proyecto",
                                "ejec_proyecto",
                                "fecha_inicio_proyecto",
                                "fecha_pro_fin_proyecto",
                                "fecha_fin_proyecto",
                                "observaciones"  ],
        "FORM 5 O-PROGRAMAS SAPG":["otros_programas_proy",
                                "programa",
                                "observaciones"],
        "FORM 6 O-RECURSOS SAPG": ["otros_recursos_proy",
                                "programa",
                                "observaciones"]   
    }

    for hoja in hojas_a_analizar:
        try:
            if hoja in df_dict:
                # Obtiene las columnas numéricas
                columnas_numericas = df_dict[hoja].select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns

                # Excluye las columnas especificadas en las excepciones
                if hoja in excepciones and excepciones[hoja]:
                    columnas_numericas = [col for col in columnas_numericas if col not in excepciones[hoja]]

                # Limpia y convierte a numérico todas las columnas identificadas
                for columna in columnas_numericas:
                    df_dict[hoja][columna] = self.limpieza_numerica_bert.limpiar_valor_numerico_en_columna(df_dict[hoja][columna])

                print(f"Columnas numéricas en la hoja {hoja} procesadas con éxito.")
        except KeyError:
            print(f"La hoja '{hoja}' no está presente en el archivo de Excel.")

    # Obtén el nombre del archivo sin la extensión
    file_name_no_extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0]

    # Construir el nombre del archivo final con el prefijo "modificado_"
    output_file_name = f"modificado_{file_name_no_extension}.xlsx"
    
    # Construir la ruta completa del archivo final
    output_file_path = os.path.join(self.output_folder, output_file_name)

    # Guardar el archivo final
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        for hoja, df_hoja in df_dict.items():
            df_hoja.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=hoja, index=False)

    return output_file_path
```

e implementado bert y strip para quitar los espacios pero no los quita adjunto una foto del excel y estas librerias
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import os
import unicodedata
from datetime import datetime
from shutil import move
import torch
import numpy as np
from Levenshtein import distance
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import re

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]